# Show a set is stable and unstable under intersection

Tags: measure-theory, intersection-theory, borel-sets, dynkin-diagrams

I have two sets:

$$ G_{1} = \{(-\infty,a]:a\in \mathbb{R}\}, G_{2} = \{(a-1,a]:a\in \mathbb{R}\} $$

and I want to show two things

(a) that $G_{1}$ is stable under intersection while $G_{2}$ is not stable under intersection.

I am arguing that $(-\infty,a]$ generates $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ so $G_{1}$ kan be considered a Borel $\sigma$-algebra and all $\sigma$-algebra are stable under intersection. Is that argument sound?
How would you argue that $G_{2}$ is not stable under intersection?

(b) that $\delta(G_{1}) = \sigma(G_{1})$ and $\sigma(G_{1})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

I know that if a Dynkin system is stable under finite intersection then it is also a $\sigma$-algebra and I have a Theorem saying that if a $\sigma$-algebra generator $\mathscr{G} \subset \mathscr{P}(X)$ is stable under finite intersection then $\delta(G_{1}) = \sigma(G_{1})$, but how do I actually show this with $G_{1}$?

About $\sigma(G_{1})=\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, has it something to do with the family of closed sets in the $\sigma$-algebra?

Any inputs?

Comment: By 'stable under intersection', do you mean that the intersection of any two elements is also an element?

Comment: Yes like this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stable_under_Intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question (a)**

Take $(-\infty, a] = A \in G_1$ and $(-\infty, b] = b \in G_1$, with $a < b$. Then:

$$C = A \cap B = A \in G_1.$$

As a consequence, $G_1$ is stable under intersection.
Note that in case that $a > b$, then

$$C = A \cap B = B \in G_1.$$

---

Take $(a-1, a] = A \in G_2$ and $(b-1, b] = b \in G_2$, with $a < b-1$. Then:

$$C = A \cap B = \emptyset \not\in G_2.$$

As a consequence, $G_2$ is **not** stable under intersection.
Note that in case that $b < a -1$, then

$$C = A \cap B = \emptyset \not\in G_2.$$

Comment: Thanks that is great way of showing it.